# Cant get data from observable in other component Angular 8

Tags: angular

im trying to passa the susbscrive value but it cames as Subscriber  object and i cant acess it

login.ts

```
  makeLoginRequest(form:any){
     this.authenticationMiddleWare.login(form).then(res => {
     console.log(" res", res)

     }).catch(err =>{
     console.log(" err", err)

     })

  }
```

service.ts

```
 async login(form:any):Promise<any>  {

    const options = this.loginRequestOptions();

    var result :any;

   result = await this.communication.request(
      this.httpModel.PAYLOAD = {
        needCache:true,
        queryString:"",
        params: {    
          Username: form.value.email,
          Password :form.value.password
        },
        httpRequest:"POST",
        responseType: "json",
        api: "/api/v0/usersaccount/",
        endpoint: "login",
        headers: options

    }).subscribe( (res:any) => {
      result = res // =>   I WANT THIS RESULT ON LOGIN

    }, (err:any) =>{
      result = err

    }) 

    return await result;

  }
```

I know its the return but i cant figure it out how to so send res values to login.

Comment: I think you need your Observable to be turned into a promise with .toPromise(), or don't use async/await at all and not subscribe and just return the Observable to the makeLoginRequest and IT would subscribe in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `Observable` and subscribe where you need that result, or convert to `Promise` and `.then` where you need the result

```
return this.communication.request( // RETURN RIGHT AWAY
      this.httpModel.PAYLOAD = {
        needCache:true,
        queryString:"",
        params: {    
          Username: form.value.email,
          Password :form.value.password
        },
        httpRequest:"POST",
        responseType: "json",
        api: "/api/v0/usersaccount/",
        endpoint: "login",
        headers: options

    })
```